# Android: Can AsyncTask recreate itself?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. In an Async's `doInBackground`, some data is downloaded.
2. In the Async's `onPostExecute`, the downloaded data is processed and if the data isn't what it has to be, I want the AsyncTask to restart itself from the `onPostExecute`.

My question is: is it bad practice to call `new MyTask().execute();` from the Async itself to make it restart? Is it okay to do that or is there a better way?

Comment: use a thread with looper. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you use a Looper with an AsyncTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like your icon Merlin. I'm sure there's a dragon out there too.

You probably just don't want an `AsyncTask` for that (`AsyncTask` wasn't intended to be a catch-all solution to concurrency in Android- even less `Looper` or the like, which is for dispatching things of a completely different nature. Oh and not `new Thread` with a Looper- you'd just be redesigning something that's readily available in Java and is widely regarded as one of the most reliable and desirable features of the language!)

Take a look at an executor service ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), [nice android docs with really good example similar to your purpose!](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)) or even a scheduled executor service ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)). `java.util.concurrent` is your best of friends!

This way you can create a task and submit it more than once without having to call `new`.

Just another question: `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread. From the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes
```

You say **"the downloaded data is processed"**. Does this require touching UI elements? Shouldn't this be asynchronous too, therefore not in `onPostExecute`?

Best of luck!

Comment: Well, processed is a bit of a big word. It's a json and in the `onPostExecute` it's converted to a json.

Comment: Sure, but you don't *need* to run it on the UI thread, so why go out of your way to do it? You only need to get onto UI thread in Android if you need to touch UI elements; and you have lots of nice ways to post onto the UI message queue. Some significant (by no means a majority, but significant) proportion of the stalls and crashes I've been asked to debug is because the developers have done too much on the UI thread!

Comment: Thank you Tom, I'll take a look at this! I'll let you know if it worked out!

Comment: Just added a link to some nice android docs which show how to do something similar to what you want to achieve! Best of luck!

Comment: It's a nice solution! Working like a charm! Thank you Tom! PS. Glad you like the Merlin tv series too ;)